# How to visualize features extracted from ResNet50

Tags: python, keras, feature-extraction, resnet

I have extracted features using the ResNet50 network pre-trained on ImageNet (using Keras framework), the features were extracted from the average pooling layer (1 x 1 x 2048), is it possible to visualize them somehow?

```
format: 
Id --- n0 ---------- n1 ------ n2 --------- n3 ---------- n4 --------------- ... --n2047
0, 0.29248324, 0.20878232, 0.10046699, 0.021526804, 0.8542325000000001, 0.12660244, 0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not clear why you want to do this but maybe you could use a heatmap

```
import seaborn as sns; sns.set_theme()
ax = sns.heatmap(features)
```

Comment: Thank you but i guess the thing is how to decode these features into a 3 dimensional visible image